# Can't add title to mapbox map

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox

I tried to create several maps and saved as png files. In cycle I got all mapes per `year`. I want to add which year on the map, and I tried `title=i` and `fig.update_layout(title_text=i, title_x=0.5)`, but it does not work.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
year = [1980,1981,1983]
lat = [60.572959,  60.321403, 56.990280]
lon = [40.572759,  41.321203, 36.990299]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(year,lat,lon)),
               columns =['year', 'lat', 'lon'])
for idx, i in enumerate(sorted(dataframe['year'].unique())):
     #for x in range(1980,2022):
    sp = sp1[sp1['year']==i]
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(dataframe, lat='lat', lon="lon",
                        color_discrete_sequence=["fuchsia"], zoom=2, height=400, opacity=0.3, title = i)
    fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
    fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
    fig.update_layout(title_text=i, title_x=0.5)
    fig.write_image("all/plot{idx}.png".format(idx=idx))
```

I put the picture of one map as example. I want to add `year` for every map in any place.
[image: my_example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `annotations` attribute of the previously created layout object in the `update_layout` method to add text - specified by the `x` and `y` coordinates.

```
fig.update_layout(annotations=[
    dict(text=i, x=0.5, y=0.5, font_size=15, showarrow=False)
])
```

Play around with the `x` and `y` coordinates to find the proper position you want to place your text at.

Answer (score 1):

All you should do is to specify a space for the title by customizing the margin:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_us_airport_traffic.csv"
)
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="lat", lon="long", size="cnt", zoom=3)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")

fig.update_layout(
    title_x=0.5,
    title_y=0.95,
    title_text="2011_february_us_airport_traffic",
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "b": 0, "t": 80}
)

fig.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]